# Building a QGridLayout with images using QPixMap?

Tags: c++, qt, graphics

I' making a program that reads in files from a directory and takes some information from said files. I want to output this information to a QGridLayout with the following format:

[image]

I was thinking of using a QLabel array and pixmaping the images to the labels. That kind of works so far but I'm not sure how to attach the QLabels at the bottom to the images on top. Could anyone explain how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put each image and label into a `QVBoxLayout` and then add it into your `QGridLayout` using `QGridLayout::addLayout`.